# Two questions on homotopy category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

I am learning [Homotopy category of chain complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes) from wikipedia. There are two places I do not understand：

1.Let $K(A)$ (respectively, $D(A)$) be a homotopy category (respectively, derived category) of chain complexes. There is a canonical functor $K(A) \rightarrow D(A)$ if $A$ is abelian.

My idea is as follows: $D(A)$ is obtained by localizing $K(A)$ at the set of quasi-isomorphisms.  The canonical functor $\pi: K(A) \rightarrow D(A)$ maps $f: M \to N$ to $1_{N} \circ f$. Is my understanding correct？

2.The homotopy category $\textrm{Ho}(C)$ of a differential graded category $C$ is defined to have the same objects as $C$, but morphisms are defined by $\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Ho}(C)}(X,Y)=H^{0}\textrm{Hom}_{C}(X,Y)$.

About 2, what is the meaning of $\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Ho}(C)}(X,Y)=H^{0}\textrm{Hom}_{C}(X,Y)$?

Edited to add: A differential graded category $C$ (dg category for short)  is a category whose morphism sets are complexes: 
\begin{align*}
\cdots \to \textrm{Hom}^{-1}(X,Y) \to \textrm{Hom}^{0}(X,Y) \to \textrm{Hom}^{1}(X,Y) \to \cdots
\end{align*}
$\textrm{Hom}_{C}(X,Y)=\oplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \textrm{Hom}_{n}(X,Y)$.

Comment: 1) Yes, $\pi$ is the localisation functor.
2) Since $C$ is differential graded category, $\mathrm{Hom}_C(X,Y)$ is a complex of abelian groups, and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ho}(C)}(X,Y)$ is its zeroth cohomology, which is an abelian group.

Comment: @bing What do you mean with $1_N$? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: See the wiki article on dg categories for an explanation of how the category of chain complexes becomes a dg category. For chain complexes $X$ and $Y$, in the chain complex $Hom_C(X,Y)$ a $0$-chain is a map of graded abelian groups $X\to Y$, it is a $0$-cycle if it is a chain map, and two such maps differ by a boundary if and only if they are chain homotopic.

Comment: @ Denis Nardin I mean that $1_N$ is the identity morphism from $N$ to $N$. I view $1_N$ as a quasi-isomorphism from $N$ to $N$.

Comment: @ user337830 I am a new. Could you explain more concretely about (2)? Thank you very much.

Comment: @ Tom Goodwillie  Could you explain more concretely about (2)? Thank you very much.

Comment: @bing: Concerning your edit, $\mathrm{Hom}_C(X,Y)$ is not only the graded abelian group $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}\mathrm{Hom}^n(C,Y)$. It is the whole complex $\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(X,Y)$, including its terms $\mathrm{Hom}^n(X,Y)$'s and more importantly its differentials $\mathrm{Hom}^n(X,Y)\to \mathrm{Hom}^{n+1}(X,Y)$.

Comment: @bing: $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ho}(C)}(X,Y)$ is the [zeroth cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology) of the complex $\cdots \to \mathrm{Hom}^{-1}(X,Y) \to \mathrm{Hom}^{0}(X,Y) \to \mathrm{Hom}^{1}(X,Y) \to \cdots$.

Comment: @user337830 Thank you very much. But I want to know the connection between $\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Ho}(C)}(X,Y)$ and the chain homotopy of complexes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes .

Comment: @bing: people might not realised that you've tried to tag them in the above comments. You should not leave a space between the @ sign and the username, besides I think you should use the username rather than the displayed name, that is it should've been denis-nardin and tom-goodwillie. Once you type @ followed immediately by the first letter of the username, you can choose it from the pop-up list.